# Making https requests on AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, onesignal

Recently discovered AWS and i'm doing great, today i want to send a test notification to my iPhone X. I'm trying to do so when my database get's an update, Using the dynamoDB trigger blueprint.

**Regular Notifications Delivered on the Dashboard works**

This is what i have tried to so far, I'm neither getting the rep console log on CloudWatch nor an error.

```
console.log('Loading function');
const async = require('async');
const https = require('https');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

    const name = "35b83a10-9f46-4c2c-95e1-22c6d40005a8"; 

    var message = { 
      app_id: "appid",
      contents: {"en": "Your order has arrived at your doorstep"},
      include_player_ids: ["14894201-64f7-486a-b65e-6beedf5880f1",name,"8e0f21fa-9a5a-4ae7-a9a6-ca1f24294b86"]
     };

    sendNotification(message);

    console.log("Activation change detected. message sent");
    return `Successfully processed ${event.Records.length} records.`;
};


var sendNotification = function(data) {
  var headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "Authorization": "Basic hidden_in_question"
  };

  var options = {
    host: "onesignal.com",
    port: 443,
    path: "/api/v1/notifications",
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers
  };

  var req = https.request(options, function(res) {  
    res.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log("rep:");
      console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    });
  });

  req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("ERROR:");
    console.log(e);
  });

  req.write(JSON.stringify(data));
  req.end();
};
```

I do not get the message on my iPhone. What seems to be the problem here?

But getting:

> Activation change detected. message sent

on the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTP request is an async action which means you need to wait for the response, but in your case you are returning from the handler just after calling the function.
In order to fix this you need to wait for http request to finish before returning from handler. The following method assumes that you are using nodejs v8.x.

```
const https = require('https');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

    const name = "35b83a10-9f46-4c2c-95e1-22c6d40005a8"; 

    var message = { 
      app_id: "appid",
      contents: {"en": "Your order has arrived at your doorstep"},
      include_player_ids: ["14894201-64f7-486a-b65e-6beedf5880f1",name,"8e0f21fa-9a5a-4ae7-a9a6-ca1f24294b86"]
     };

    await sendNotification(message);

    console.log("Activation change detected. message sent");
    return `Successfully processed ${event.Records.length} records.`;
};


var sendNotification = function(data) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Authorization": "Basic hidden_in_question"
      };

      var options = {
        host: "onesignal.com",
        port: 443,
        path: "/api/v1/notifications",
        method: "POST",
        headers: headers
      };

      var req = https.request(options, function(res) {  
        res.on('data', function(data) {
          console.log("rep:");
          console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        });
        res.on('end', resolve);
      });

      req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("ERROR:");
        console.log(e);
        reject(e);
      });

      req.write(JSON.stringify(data));
      req.end();
  });
}
```

Comment: glad to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (body) {
    console.log('Body: ' + body);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

req.write(data);
req.end();
```

Comment: I am using this code to post body data with request and its work fine for me in local but its didn't work on lambda

Comment: Is there any other solution through i can post raw body in json

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, better than give an answer with description, information... and comments after it, edit your previous post and add your comments.